# ¿Como obtener datos con funcion PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados espero se encuentren bien, de mi parte estaría muy agradecido de su ayuda.

Tengo una funcion PHP para obtener filas de una base de datos MySQL, cuando hay datos todo funciona bien, pero cuando no existen filas o coincidencias con la búsqueda. Me arroja el error **"Undefined variable: arr"**. Como puedo evitar dicho error ?

Dejo a continuación el Script

conexion.php

```
//OBTENER CONJUNTO DE DATOS
    public function obtenerdatos($datos,$tabla,$condiciones,$conjunto) {
        $query = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT $datos FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones");
        $query->execute($conjunto);

            while ($fila = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $arr []= $fila;
            }
        return $arr;
    }
```

archivo X

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/logica/conexion/conexion.php';
$con =  new Conexion();
$datos = $con->obtenerdatos("*","usuarios","correo = ?",['dgdfgdf']);
echo count($datos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta sucediendo porque no has declarado la variable, fíjate que la declaras e inicializas dentro del `while`, lo que ocurre solo cuando hay datos, pero si no hay datos esta variable no se declara, por lo tanto, sucede el error. Para arreglarlo solo debes declarar e inicializar tu variable antes del ciclo, de esta manera si no hay datos retornas un arreglo vacio, asi:

```
//OBTENER CONJUNTO DE DATOS
public function obtenerdatos($datos,$tabla,$condiciones,$conjunto) {
    $query = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT $datos FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones");
    $query->execute($conjunto);
    $arr=[];
    while ($fila = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $arr []= $fila;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, olvide por completo declarar la variable antes.